# Remove Categories from Product Page Title

Tags: magento2.2, seo, page-title

When navigating to a product in Magento 2, through multiple categories - i.e. site.com/tops/bras - if there is no manually set SEO title, it adds Tops - Bras to the product page title, what would be the most efficient way to remove this (without manually editing every product SEO title).

Example:
[image]